# Find a sentence in an html page displayed in the browser and Highlight it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, frontend

I'm using asp.net mvc to display a .html  document that I know exactly what it contains.

I have this method in my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetHtmlPage(string path)
{
    return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
}
```

and I have this Simple view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ManageDocument";
}
<h2>ManageDocument</h2>
@Html.Action("GetHtmlPage", "myController", new { path = Model.documentPath })
```

The document is displayed with no problems. But i want to **Highlight a specific sentence** that I know it exists somewhere in the document.

What I mean is, I'm trying to implement a JavaScript code maybe to find that specific sentence i want to highlight in the document and highlight it! 
I read about window.find() in JavaScript but my asp.net solution doesn't seem to recognize it.

I'm using VS2015 Enterprise

Comment: Try mark.js, a highlighter for the web

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to wrap the text with some tags and apply whatever custom styles you might need. Let's suppose that you have the following markup:

```
<div>
    This is some specific sentence
</div>
```

and you want to end up with this:

```
<div>
    This is <strong>some specific</strong> sentence
</div>
```

You could try the `:contains` selector to locate the desired portion of the text and then wrap it with some tags:

```
$("div:contains('some specific')").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(/(some specific)/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");
});
```

And here's a [`sample fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/jz86v8we/).

Comment: What if i want to insert a variable in that. say var sen = 'some specific' ??

Comment: What's preventing you from inserting a variable in the code? Just replace the hardcoded value with a variable, it's trivial: `$("div:contains(" + sen + ")")`. And also: `var regex = new RegExp("(" + sen + ")", "g");`. And finally: `return html.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");`

Comment: Dear Sir, My knowledge is preventing me :D, lemme try

Comment: Also don't forget to account for any special characters that your variable might contain which could interfere with the jQuery selector and the regular expression. You will need to properly escape them before passing it to the `RegExp` constructor.