# Highlighting an html document expression in Asp.net mvc using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to highlight a specific sentence in an html document displayed on the web browser.

I have this action in my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetHtmlPage(string path)
{
    return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
}
```

and I have this **view** that shows the html document in the specified path.

```
@model TextPlagiarismWebApp.Models.ViewModels.ManageDocumentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManageDocument";
}

<h2>ManageDocument</h2>

@Html.Action("GetHtmlPage", "Upload", new { path = Model.documentPath })

<script type="text/javascript">
    var sen = @Model.sentence["sentence"];
    $("div:contains('" + sen + "')").html(function (_, html) {
        var regex = new RegExp("(" + sen + ")", "g");
        return html.replace(regex, '<span style="background-color:#FFFF00">$1</span>');
    });
</script>
```

I debugged the program and the sen variable is what I would expect:

```
var sen = @Model.sentence["sentence"];
```

But despite that, it's not highlighting the specific sentences that I'm looking for. It only shows the original html document.

Let's take this example where I'm sure the sentence exists:

```
var sen = "Requirements for breeding tanks vary with each species. Separate tanks may be required."
```

**HTML:**

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='text-align:justify;mso-layout-grid-align:none;
text-autospace:none'><span lang=EN-AU style='color:black'>Requirements for
breeding tanks vary with each species. Separate tanks may be required.<o:p>
</o:p></span></p>
```

But the sentence is not highlighted, and I can't figure out why.

Any suggestions as to what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a sentence in an html page displayed in the browser and Highlight it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556535/find-a-sentence-in-an-html-page-displayed-in-the-browser-and-highlight-it)

Comment: I check your previous question answer. it's look's good for this question.

Comment: your variable is good. but problem in your HTML. A break line after "Requirements for".

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
  $("body").html(function (_, innerHTML) {
        var regex = new RegExp("(" + sen + "'))", "g");
        return innerHTML.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').replace(regex, '<span style="background-color:#FFFF00">$1</span>');
    });
```

the first replace will `.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')` will remove multiple spaces and `.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '')` will remove the break line in paragraph

here is example https://jsfiddle.net/jz86v8we/10/

**Edit**

you can use [Jquery-Highlight-5.js](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) by adding

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-5.js"></script>
```

and in script use

```
$("body").highlight("The Business");
```

and add this to your `css` file

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow }
```

Comment: I have a bigger document and i want to highlight "The Business"

Comment: @NasriYatim you should use this http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: @NasriYatim i have updated the answer and download jquery.highlight-5.js file if its not working

Comment: Not working, does not highlight and screw up the layout